# iperf3 results in packets per second?

Tags: udp, bandwidth, iperf, iperf3

Can `iperf3` report measurements also in terms of packets per second, when generating UDP traffic?

A typical output with the verbose mode is the following:

```
Test Complete. Summary Results:
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.64 GBytes  1.41 Gbits/sec  0.010 ms  804029/1208925 (67%)  
[  4] Sent 1208925 datagrams
CPU Utilization: local/sender 99.6% (16.4%u/83.3%s), remote/receiver 0.1% (0.0%u/0.1%s)

iperf Done.
```

I see that in `iperf2` one could specify the input rate in `pps`, but there is no mentioning of the measured received rate (I don't see this feature in `iperf3` anyway)

Comment: So, is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 4):

I don't see an option for pps in iperf3, however the link below details a way to get what you are looking for.

https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/benchmarking-throughput-and-packet-count-with-iperf3/2791

Run your iperf3 test as you normally would. On the server create a script containing the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

INTERVAL="1"  # update interval in seconds

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo
        echo usage: $0 [network-interface]
        echo
        echo e.g. $0 eth0
        echo
        echo shows packets-per-second
        exit
fi

IF=$1

while true
do
        R1=`cat /sys/class/net/$1/statistics/rx_packets`
        T1=`cat /sys/class/net/$1/statistics/tx_packets`
        sleep $INTERVAL
        R2=`cat /sys/class/net/$1/statistics/rx_packets`
        T2=`cat /sys/class/net/$1/statistics/tx_packets`
        TXPPS=`expr $T2 - $T1`
        RXPPS=`expr $R2 - $R1`
        echo "TX $1: $TXPPS pkts/s RX $1: $RXPPS pkts/s"
 done
```

This will give you an output in terms of packets per second.